# Read from CSV file into array, parse through array, access second element of each line

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, csv

I'm extremely new to programming in Perl, and new to the programming world in general.

I'm trying to write a program that opens a CSV file, reads it into an array, and parses through it using split().

Each field of the CSV file contains four things:

```
  $full_name, $user_name, $password, $con_password
```

My problem is that I need to access the second element of each line (user_name). Then I need to put all the user names into an array so I can work with that.

I've done the split, but I don't know how to make sure I get the second element of each line.

This is what I have:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use CGI qw(:standard);
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

 my $file = '/home/2014/amosqu/public_html/cgi-bin/Members.csv';
 open(my $csv, '>>', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!";

 #i get these values from a form in an html file
 my $full_name = param('full_name');
 my $user_name = param('user_name');
 my $password = param('password');
 my $con_password = param('con_password');

 #array to store user names
 my @users = ();

 while(my $lines = <$csv>) {
     chomp $lines;
     my @fields = split(/,/, $lines);
 }

 #access second element and put into @users ???
```

Comment: `$fields[1]` will give you the second element. (starts from zero)

Comment: and to put into @users?

Comment: `push @users, $fields[1];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to write something like this...

```
my @list;
open (my $csv, '<', $file) || die "cant open";
foreach (<$csv>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split(/\,/);
   push @list, $fields[1];
}
```

In your code the file is opened for appending not reading.

Comment: would this happen for every line in my CSV file?

Comment: Look at my example?  You need to use '<' instead of '>>'

Comment: My program has to append some values into the Members.csv file. If i want to read as well as append should I do '+>>' ?

Comment: you can open for read & append, but it moves the file pointer to the end, so you'll need to do a seek to the beginning, but at this point in your learning career i would use ONE file handle. open/read/close, then open/append/close. trying to use two file handles will invite errors. modularize  your thought process.